# Can someone help to understand code disassembly by IDA?

Tags: ida, assembly

Can someone help to understand code disassembly by IDA?

Basically this use for calculate key from seed. Here I would like to understand the logic and also I would like to know what would be the output length of key.

Sorry code was larger so I'm posting image but sharing DLL file for reference.

[DLL (skey.dll size:64 KB)](https://mega.nz/file/OQcR1Baa#dCy_8pXtPIH1_lsd8F2gQsquVqQ9rJfP41f4bP7XSSw)

[image: Code image]

Comment: Please post code as text (use code formatting). Also add your observations and best guess about what the code is doing. What specific parts are you having trouble with?

Comment: Basically this use for calculate key from seed. Here I would like to understand logic. Also I would like to know what would be the output length of key.

Comment: Please add this information to the question

Comment: Hint: `cmp [esp +var_8], 14h`  determines maximum length of key.